# Weird excel formatting...is this possible?

Tags: excel, formatting

I made a table in Excel and the inputs are going to be single letters. Is it possible to format the table so that, if a certain letter is inputted, the cell automatically changes to a specified colour???

Thanks, sorry if this isn't the right place to put this question.

Comment: Look up "conditional formatting".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you make use of conditional formatting.

Let's say your table is in A1:G5. Click on conditional formatting. Pick 'Highlight Cell Rules' and 'Equal To...'.

Insert the value you want to highlight and pick the highlight from the dropdown button.